# Error While Fetching with Retrofit Library

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I created function inside MainActivity which is called when refresh button is pressed

```
public void callWeatherAPI(){

        SharedPreferences SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

        final String strUserName = SP.getString("username", "NA");
        int defaultval = Integer.parseInt(strUserName);




        WeatherAPI weatherAPI = APIHandler.getApiInterface();
        weatherAPI.getWeatherCity(defaultval, new Callback<StudentData>() {

            public void success(final StudentData arg0, Response arg1) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), arg0.getStudentName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), WeatherData.getWeatherCity().getDescription(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            public void failure(RetrofitError arg0) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OPS, some kind of problem had happend! :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And created a static class inside MainActivity

```
public static class Student{
    public String exam_roll;
    public String class_no;
    public String block_no;
    public String name;

}
public static class StudentData{
    Student student;
    public int success;


    public int getStudentName() {
        return success;
    }
}
```

Whose json is

```
{"success":1,"student":[{"exam_roll":"1212","class_no":"121","block_no":"1221","name":"rohit"}]}
```

I have set the callback functions to direct to the **StudentData class**

```
public interface WeatherAPI {

//@GET("/weather")
@GET("/")

void getWeatherCity(@Query("pid") int pid, Callback<MainActivity.StudentData> callback);
```

}

Don't know what is the problem with this it returns the retrofit error function

The error with retrofit was

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, use [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) site for generating your models.
**StudentData**:

```
public class StudentData {

@Expose
private Integer success;
@Expose
private List<Student> student = new ArrayList<Student>();

/**
* 
* @return
* The success
*/
public Integer getSuccess() {
return success;
}

/**
* 
* @param success
* The success
*/
public void setSuccess(Integer success) {
this.success = success;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The student
*/
public List<Student> getStudent() {
return student;
}

/**
* 
* @param student
* The student
*/
public void setStudent(List<Student> student) {
this.student = student;
}

}
```

**Student**:

```
public class Student {

@SerializedName("exam_roll")
@Expose
private String examRoll;
@SerializedName("class_no")
@Expose
private String classNo;
@SerializedName("block_no")
@Expose
private String blockNo;
@Expose
private String name;

/**
* 
* @return
* The examRoll
*/
public String getExamRoll() {
return examRoll;
}

/**
* 
* @param examRoll
* The exam_roll
*/
public void setExamRoll(String examRoll) {
this.examRoll = examRoll;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The classNo
*/
public String getClassNo() {
return classNo;
}

/**
* 
* @param classNo
* The class_no
*/
public void setClassNo(String classNo) {
this.classNo = classNo;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The blockNo
*/
public String getBlockNo() {
return blockNo;
}

/**
* 
* @param blockNo
* The block_no
*/
public void setBlockNo(String blockNo) {
this.blockNo = blockNo;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The name
*/
public String getName() {
return name;
}

/**
* 
* @param name
* The name
*/
public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how can i retrieve name 
 public void success(final StudentData studentData, Response arg1) {


                Log.d("Debug",studentData.student.get(0));

            }
I get null point exception

Comment: Instead of `Log.d("Debug",studentData.student.get(0));`, do next: `Log.d("Debug",studentData);` and show me result

Comment: It is not applicable ! Log.d requires string

Comment: @ShresthaRohit, Log.d("Debug",studentData + "");

Comment: D/Debug﹕ ku.example.com.seatplanku.MainActivity$StudentData@b2fc3010

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
The problem is in your StudentData class. 
Instead of an instance of Student you had to create the class like this:

```
public static class StudentData { 
    List<Student> student;
    public int success;
    ...
}
```

The JSON shows clearly that the element with the "student" key is an array of Student instances.

Comment: {"success":1,"student":[{"exam_roll":"1212","class_no":"121","block_no":"1221","name":"rohit"}]} it has a array in it !

Comment: I know, I saw the JSON. But maybe the structure of the original JSON was different than that. Did you try with the List callback?

Comment: I tried with the same code i posted above i got result for the success in json Now i am struggling how to access to array object i.e. exam_roll,class_no .

Comment: Oh now I see where the problem is...look at the EDIT of my answer

Comment: Okay i did as you said now in this session
 public void success(List<StudentData> studentDatas, Response response) {
                    
            } 
how do i access the json data ?  i haven't used List much

Comment: Leave the Retrofit @GET method as you wrote in first place. Change only the StudentData class. With the students List you can use the .get(int n) method to obtain the element at index 'n' inside the list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82952/discussion-between-shrestha-rohit-and-nicopasso).